# Understanding C++ code

Tags: c++

I have been following a tutorials to make a linked list, and i'm trying to understand the code to the fullest. I just have some questions considering the code you guys might help me answer (i hope). This function is to insert a element.

```
node *temp = new node;
temp->nameOfFood = nameOfFood;
temp->eatCalories = eatCalories;
temp->next = NULL;
head = temp;
last = temp;
```

I understand this code (kinda), but i don't understand the last part - why does both head and last equals temp;? Then both the head, and last will be the same element/value?

And then the next part. Checking if the list is empty, elsewise inserting a element.

```
if(isEmpty(head)) //Cheacking if list is empty
    insertNode(head, last, nameOfFood, eatCalories);
else
{
    node *temp = new node;
    temp->nameOfFood = nameOfFood;
    temp->eatCalories = eatCalories;
    temp->next = NULL;
    last->next = temp;
    last = temp;
```

I understand that you create the new node, and forward from there, but then last->next = temp; and last = temp; i'm not sure i understand why?

Comment: If you only have one node, what else would head and tail point to?

Comment: I don't know. It's just that when i add the new element, i would have imagined that only the last value would be =temp; because the other way, the first element, and last element would contain the same values. 

I'm making a list of elements, and when i add new element, only the last value should be changed, so the new elements would be added at the bottom of the list. If you know what i mean?

Comment: Sometimes it helps to draw what is happening on paper to understand how an algorithm/a piece of code works.

Comment: I think that test should be `if (not isEmpty(head))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a list of three nodes, it will look something like

```
+--------+     +--------+     +--------+
| node 1 | --> | node 2 | --> | node 3 |
+--------+     +--------+     +--------+
```

The "arrows" is the `next` pointer.

Now with this list, `head` should point at "node 1" while `last` should point at "node 3".

What the two lines you are wondering about does, is make the `last` nodes `next` pointer point to the new node, and then make `last` point to the new node, thereby adding the new node last in the list.

So with the list above, and adding one node, then it will lokk like

```
+--------+     +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
| node 1 | --> | node 2 | --> | node 3 | --> | node 4 |
+--------+     +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
```

And `last` has been updated to now point at "node 4".

Comment: Thanks for the help. Makes great sense, and very helpful with the illustration!

Answer (score 0):

*Why does both head and last equals temp;? Then both the head, and last will be the same element/value?*

Because in this list you only have one element, so this element is the first and the last at the same time.

*but then `last->next = temp;` and `last = temp`; i'm not sure i understand why?*

`last->next = temp` is actually linking the last element of the list to the one that you just created, which is going to be the next in your list. And, since this is the new last element, you must update the value of `last` by doing `last = temp`.

Comment: Joachim answered my question, but thanks for providing input. It's all helping me understand :-)